# for an abelian group G prove the identity $-(-a-b)=a+b$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

for an Abelian group $G$ under $(+)$ if $a,b \in$ G
then show that $\\-(-a-b)=a+b$
what I did is the following

since $G$ is a group then for every $a$ there exist $-a\in G$        ,
also $((-a)+(-b)) \in G $
$\implies ((-a)+(-b))$ has inverse $-((-a)+(-b))$ since $\forall a \in G$ there exist a unique inverse which is $-a$  since we know that the unique identity under $+$ is $0 $  so

$(-a-b)+(-(-a-b))=0 \implies -(-a-b)=a+b$

is it a valid proof ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.

You argued that $-((-a)+(-b))$ is the inverse of $(-a-b)$.

Show that $(a+b)$ is also the inverse of $(-a-b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, first prove that $a+b$ is an inverse of $-a-b$. Indeed, $(a+b)+(-a-b)=0$.

Second, the inverse of a group element $c$ is uniquely determined and is therefore denoted by $-c$.

Both properties together show that $a+b = - (-a-b)$.

Comment: order of proving doesn't matter I guess but yes I need to prove that as well...